# What happened to Adria 20 years ago?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that Adria pledged her allegiance to Diablo (or the dark wanderer) 20 years ago?

What in her storyline made her go with the Evil side of things? So much that she would sacrifice her own daughter to the prime evil?

Comment: Do we really need to get down to the details? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She was secretly evil the *whole time*.  It's heavily implied that she used to co-lead the coven/cult (with Magda) that is allied with Belial in Act 2.  She came to Tristram because she felt the great evil stirring there.  After Aidan became the Dark Wanderer, (thereby becoming Diablo) they slept together to conceive Leah.

> Twenty years ago, a great and terrible power drew me to Tristram.  But Aidan, Leoric's son, defeated that power and sought to contain it within his own flesh.  It was Diablo I saw within him.  And I pledged myself to his service.  Now, at last, his grand design comes to fruition.
>
> Dear Leah, Deckard always suspected - your true father was Diablo himself!

Servitude to Diablo has always been her end goal.  Obtaining the black soulstone, trapping the prime evils, and using them to corrupt Leah and resurrect Diablo with their combined power are just stepping stones along the way.

Comment: When she betray us in Act3, she said she came for Tristan because she sensed a great power and then she learned was diablo, no? Or i missread?

Comment: She came to Tristram, met Diablo, and decided, "This. This is how I want to spend the rest of my life."